# Is there is any way i can delete entries from ldap using openldap call?

Tags: c++, ldap, openldap

Currently there is an wrapper over [openldap](http://openldap.org). it gets the search filter `(&(objectclass=xxx)(|(dn=user_1)(dn=user_2).....(dn=user_n)))` from user and calls `ldap_search_ext_s(`), using the result it deletes the dn one by one. is there is any other efficient way to do the delete operation.

Thanks,
Raj.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to delete all entries underneath a DN, the LDAP subtree delete control is supported by many professional-quality directory servers. The subtree delete control deletes a DN and all entries subordinate to that DN.

Comment: Thanks. I need to delete only certain entries. for example, i just need to delete the entries where the some attribute value is in some particular range.[id >=10 and id <=100]

Comment: there is no standard conditional delete

Comment: Well, there is the LDAP assertion control, which can included with a delete, and is conditional based on the filter.